# When I add a related entity, the entity state is modified not added

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.0

Like *Microsoft EFCore* adding a related entity Demo, it works. But I Change the key type to Guid, after add entity to collection navigation property, the sub entity state will be Modified, why not Added?

Database didn't contain the data, so EFCore throw an Update Exception.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var dbContext = new TestDbContext();
        var userId = new Guid("332DA567-1CF8-48DD-9424-1AD49FD6CF39");
        //init root entity first
        //var user = new AppUser(
        //    userId,
        //    "testUserName");
        //dbContext.Add(user);
        //dbContext.SaveChanges();
        var user = dbContext.AppUsers
            .Include(x => x.AppUserConfigs)
            .Where(x => x.Id.Equals(userId))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var userConfig = new AppUserConfig(Guid.NewGuid(),userId,"6666");
        user.AppUserConfigs.Add(userConfig);
        // there userConfig state is Modified, why not Added
        var entries = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        // error on Save, bacause no data in database
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

1. DbContext

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppUserConfig> AppUserConfigs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source =.;Initial Catalog=TestCode; User ID=sa;Password=*******;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("TB_AppUser");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasMany(x => x.AppUserConfigs).WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserConfig>().ToTable("TB_AppUserConfig");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

2. AppUser Entity

```
public class AppUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string UserName { get; protected set; }

    public List<AppUserConfig> AppUserConfigs { get; protected set; }

    protected AppUser()
    { 
    }

    public AppUser(
        Guid id,
        string userName)
    {
        Id = id;
        UserName = userName;
        AppUserConfigs = new List<AppUserConfig>();
    }
}
```

3. AppUserConfig Entity

```
 public class AppUserConfig
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; protected set; }
    public string CorporationId { get; protected set; }

    protected AppUserConfig()
    { 
    }

    public AppUserConfig(
        Guid id,
        Guid userId,
        string corporationId)
    {
        Id = id;
        UserId = userId;
        CorporationId = corporationId;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh! I find the error. if UserSqlserver then EFCore Default Create Id, So Set Property to No value generation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you found a solution to the problem please post a self-answer and accept it instead of answering in the comment.